# opening and manipulating text files with python

Tags: python, file, text

So I've done a lot of browsing, but I cant seem to open my text file so I can begin to manipulate it.

I saved my program in with the same file: and my first line returns no errors:

```
fpath= r'/Users/veggiepunk1363/Desktop/geoproccessing/file_list.txt'

with open(fpath) as f_in:
    dates= f_in.read()
    f_in.close()
```

But now is my file open? The text file (file_list.txt) is:

3B43.20000101.7.tif

3B43.20000201.7.tif

3B43.20000301.7.tif

3B43.20000401.7.tif

3B43.20000501.7.tif...

and so on, so now I need to assign dates(jan, feb, mar etc) instead of numbers, but I havent used anything without "" so I'm a little lost and while I can find a lot on CSV files I havent been able to find what I need on txt files so any references would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

ps. If anyone knows how to change my hard drives name to something other than veggiepunk1363 PLEASE let me know! haha

my new code:

```py
f = open('/Users/veggiepunk1363/Desktop/geoproccessing/file_listmaster3.txt','r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

Jan = filedata.replace("20001","2000Jan")
Feb = filedata.replace("20002","2000Feb")
Mar= filedata.replace("20003","2000Mar")
Apr= filedata.replace("20004","2000Apr")
May= filedata.replace("20005","2000May")
Jun= filedata.replace("20006","2000Jun")
Jul= filedata.replace("20007","2000Jul")
Aug= filedata.replace("20008","2000Aug")
Sep= filedata.replace("20009","2000Sep")
Oct= filedata.replace("20010","2000Oct")
Nov= filedata.replace("20011","2000Nov")
Dec= filedata.replace("20012","2000Dec")

f = open('/Users/veggiepunk1363/Desktop/geoproccessing/file_listmaster3.txt','w')

f.write(Jan)
f.write(Feb)
f.write(Mar)
f.write(Apr)
f.write(May)
f.write(Jun)
f.write(Jul)
f.write(Aug)
f.write(Sep)
f.write(Oct)
f.write(Nov)
f.write(Dec)
print ('The dates have been reformatted') 
f.close()
```

I know this is the long way to do what I'm trying to do, but I thought it would still work... it didnt. it tripled the size of my txt file and it looks like everything was duplicated? not quite sure what is going on.

Comment: Did you run it? Your file is open inside the `with` block and closes automatically when the block is exited (so there is no need for `dates= f_in.close()`). Your code reads the entire contents of the file into `dates`. One usually uses a for loop to read the data line by line (e.g., `for line in f_in:` instead of `read()`. Try building up a loop to process the lines and then submit an example.

Comment: Side-note: When you use a `with` statement, an explicit call to `close` is unnecessary and redundant (that's _why_ you use `with` statements, so resource cleanup is automatic and can't be accidentally omitted/skipped).

Comment: edited... I figured out the opening/closing, but had unexpected results when editing my data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. `veggiepunk1363` is not the name of your hard drive. It is the folder in which your `User` files resides on Windows.

```
fpath= r'/Users/veggiepunk1363/Desktop/geoproccessing/file_list.txt'

with open(fpath, 'r') as f_in: #opens the file with read mode 
    dates = f_in.readlines()   #returns a list of all the lines in the file into dates
```

Comment: Since there's no C drive listed, the user is probably on MacOS rather than Windows